# IE8/9 dynamically inserted elements are invisible for a nondeterministic amount of time

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Has anybody else encountered this problem and arrived at a satisfactory solution?

Basically I have a *very* complex web application which under IE9 Quirks mode (There is no possibility of switching the doctype as of right now) a specific type of element being dynamically inserted via jQuery is failing to present itself fully. It participates in page layout, but the element itself *does not appear*.

Sometimes 5 seconds later, and sometimes 30 seconds later, and sometimes even later than that, the element will finally magically appear.

I have used the F12 dev tools (both with and without the "Begin Debugging" clicked) and it does present the element in question, and it does not show the blue border indicator (as it's apparently not being rendered no rendering of its border appears, this is logical).

The temporary functioning workaround has been to dynamically remove the element, and reinsert it, in a nested `setTimeout()` chain. Then I have to re-install click event handlers.

Like this:

```
if (isQuirksMode()) {                                         
    setTimeout(function() {                                   
        var parent = jqelement.parent();                        
        var removed = jqelement.remove();                       
        setTimeout(function() {                               
            parent.append(removed);                           
            removed.children('input').click(clickcallback);
        },0);                                                 
    },0);                                                     
}                                                             
jqpage.append(jqelement);
```

This code will force the element to be inserted, removed from DOM, and inserted again, and after that it seems to correctly display.

The reason for doing it this way is that I tried adding and removing a class, in hopes it would trigger a re-render, but that did not change any behavior.

My question is, does this behavior ring any bells for anyone, and have you been able to come up with a less expensive way of getting it to behave?

Comment: On further testing it seems that doing something like resizing the IE browser window will cause enough of a re-render to bring the elements into view.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting elements as strings all in one go is much faster than injecting them individually into the DOM.

Build it up in a string - use `innerHTML` to insert.

Comment: Yes it does make sense that assembling the HTML beforehand gives it a better chance of properly rendering the first time.